# How can I declare only a subset of an array in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, subset

I'm about to do something like this :

```
my ($sec,$min,$hour,$day,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime(time);
```

But I don't need all of those variables (only $min, $hour, $mon, $year are wanted).

Is there a simple solution to declare only required fields in perl?

A simple solution to me is this but it's not realy "sexy":

```
my @day = localtime(time);
my $min = $day[1];
my $hour = $day[2];
my $day = $day[3];
...
```

Thank you in advance to any one who may be able to give me some ideas :)

Comment: Worth noting that you can lose the `time` from your call to `localtime`. If `localtime` receives no arguments then it uses the current time. Also, look at the `strftime` function from POSIX.pm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify which elements of an array you want using [slices](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices).

```
my ($min,$hour,$mon,$year) = (localtime(time))[1,2,4,5];
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, "sexy" is a little subjective, but I think this is what you mean:

```
 my (undef,$min,$hour,undef,$mon,$year) = localtime(time);
```

Comment: This definitely is a "sexy" answer :) Thanks!